# Eternicode Bootstrap Datepicker - Dynamic startDate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the eternicode bootstrap datepicker.

I'm trying to create 2 fields:

- actie_start's startdate should be tommorow
- actie_end's startdate should be the value of actie_start + 4 days

I've trying do do this for some time now but I can't seem to find the problem. Here's the code I currently have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var _startDate = new Date();
        var _endDate = new Date(_startDate.getTime() + (96 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //plus 4 days

        $('#actie_begin').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1d',
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('changeDate', function(e){
            _endDate = new Date(e.date.getTime() + (96 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //set new end date
            $('#actie_end').datepicker('setStartDate', _endDate); //dynamically set new start date for #to
        });

        $('#actie_end').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: _endDate,
            todayHighlight: false
        }).on('changeDate', function(e){
            //if current date is bigger than start date
            if (e.date.valueOf() < _startDate.valueOf()){
                alert(e.date.toString()); //called when date is changed
            }
        });
    })
```

Currenly I only get 2 datepickers, where I can pick any date. I don't get any errors in my console.